# How to disable/configure the Spring Cloud Gateway rewriting of Location headers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a setup with Spring Cloud Gateway running with consul service discovery and proxying requests to services in a cluster.

When one of these services responds with a `Location: /` header this gets rewritten on the way out thru the gateway.

The problem is that the gateway seems to add the service local hostname and port as found in Consul. This url is of course not available (or desirable) for the client.

I have verified thet the upstream server sends:
`Location: /`

(Generated by the "redirect: /" Spring MCV shorthand)

But when it reached the end client is rewritten to:
`Location: https://10.0.0.10:34567/`

(https://10.0.0.10:34567/ being the upstream location of the service in consul)

If is of course incorrect.

My problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to configure this and no indication of what classes are used (to debug) so I just don't know where to start looking for the fix.

The desired behaviour is of course to just leave the redirect unchanged.

In this particular case we use a host based routing setup:

```
.route("app", r -> r.host("app.**").uri("lb://app"))
```

Any help or hint appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing that when reaching `NettyWriteResponseFilter` the client response from `HttpClientResponse clientResponse = exchange.getAttribute(CLIENT_RESPONSE_ATTR);` already has the `Location: https://10.0.0.10:34567/` header.

Comment: The value is already present when hitting the `NettyRoutingFilter`...

Comment: By setting the `PRESERVE_HOST_HEADER_ATTRIBUTE` I can fix the problem by making the `Location` header being rewritten using the original host. Better than nothing. But I would prefer an ability to control the rewriting.